# How to set custom Origin Name in AWS CDK for CloudFront

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cloudformation, amazon-cloudfront, aws-cdk

I'm seaching a way to customize the Origin Name (TargetOriginId) of CloudFront Distributions in AWS CDK. This is my existing code:

```js
const backendCloudfront = new cloudfront.CloudFrontWebDistribution(this, 'BackendCF', {
  originConfigs: [
    {
      s3OriginSource: {
        s3BucketSource: s3Bucket,
        originAccessIdentity: oai,
      },
      behaviors: [{isDefaultBehavior: true}, { pathPattern: '/*', allowedMethods: cloudfront.CloudFrontAllowedMethods.GET_HEAD }],
    },
  ],
});
```

This is the generated ExampleStack.template.json:

```json
"BackendCFCFDistribution7FE8ADFE": {
   "Type": "AWS::CloudFront::Distribution",
   "Properties": {
    "DistributionConfig": {
     "CacheBehaviors": [
      {
       "AllowedMethods": [
        "GET",
        "HEAD"
       ],
       "CachedMethods": [
        "GET",
        "HEAD"
       ],
       "Compress": true,
       "ForwardedValues": {
        "Cookies": {
         "Forward": "none"
        },
        "QueryString": false
       },
       "PathPattern": "/*",
       "TargetOriginId": "origin1",
       "ViewerProtocolPolicy": "redirect-to-https"
      }
     ],
[...]
```

I'm talking about this line of code of the generated json:

> `"TargetOriginId": "origin1"`,

How to change the Origin Name of this permanently, without touching the auto-generated json?

[Screenshot of the AWS Console referring to Origin Name](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d0IHB.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't found any indication in the `CDK` [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_cloudfront.CloudFrontWebDistribution.html) to support changing the `TargetOriginId`, but the great thing about `CDK` is there are L1 constructs to support cases such as these. There is still a way to achieve what you want, it is just not as pretty as the L2 construct `CloudFrontWebDistribution`. Mind you under the hood L2 constructs are all made up of L1 constructs. This seems like a good open source contribution use case ;)

```js
    const s3Bucket = new Bucket(this, "my-bucket");
    const oai = new OriginAccessIdentity(this, "my-oia");

    // Define the CloudFront distribution with CfnDistribution instead
    const backendCloudfront = new CfnDistribution(this, "BackendCF", {
      distributionConfig: {
        enabled: true,
        origins: [
          {
            domainName: s3Bucket.bucketDomainName,
            id: "myTargetName",
            s3OriginConfig: {
              originAccessIdentity: oai.originAccessIdentityId,
            },
          },
        ],
        defaultCacheBehavior: {
          targetOriginId: "myTargetName", // Referencing the origin by its ID above
          viewerProtocolPolicy: "allow-all",
          // Further configuration as needed
        },
        // Additional configuration: cache behaviors, comment, custom error responses, etc.
      },
    });
```

Then once you run `cdk synth` the generated CloudFront Distribution will have the proper `TargetOriginId` name (I'll provide the image of the `template.json` which the code snippet generated)

[image]